# How to fix slow comment query?

Tags: plugins, wp-query, customization, comments, wpdb

My site has a very modified version of the [WP Unread Comments](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-unread-comments/) plugin. The widget displays a list of posts with unread comments in the sidebar. My issue is that the database query that generates the list of comments is very slow and I don't know how to fix it.

I think that the problem is in the following segment of code. The main change that I made here to the original plugin code was to add the date_query parameter.

```
$comments = get_comments( array(
            'number' => $number, 
            'order' => $order, 
            'status' => 'approve', 
            'post_status' => 'publish', 
            'date_query' => array(
                array('after' => '2 weeks ago',))
            ) );

        $output .= $args['before_widget'];
        if ( $title ) {
            $output .= $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
                  }
        $output .= '<ul id="recentcomments">';

        $postarray=array();
        $commentarray=array();
        $number = $instance['number_unread'];
```

The site currently has about 130,000 comments. I recently deleted comments older than 2 years. This removed about 300,000 comments and the Unread Comments plugin started working faster. The time shown by Query Monitor was cut by two-thirds.

In short, I think the solution may involve limiting how much of the comments database is read by the query. I thought that's what I was doing when I added the date_query parameter. Any tips on how I can make the code more efficient would be super welcome!

Comment: Meta queries ARE slow and expensive. There's not much to do to improve the performance.

Comment: Is there any caching in-place on the site? You may be able to cache comment results to avoid database lookups on every load

Comment: @Welcher There is a lot of dynamic content on the site and when I've tried to implement caching in the past site components have failed to update regularly for at least some users. So, some things are cached (e.g., site logo) but most of the site doesn't use caching. I'd be interested in trying it out though for the comment results but I don't know how to do that. I know how to cache things like css and js but not how to cache database queries.